# Add a configurable and animatable video filter like in Snapchat

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, snapchat

I want to create android application with video filters like in snapchat. The problem is that i can't find library like SCRecorder in IOS, I already added FFmpeg in application but even with ffmpeg i can't applying filters over the image or videos.
Do you have any library or idea/code to solve this problem ?
Below is screenshot from snapchat
[image]

Comment: What is wrong with this question that some people put minuses ?

Comment: Have you implemented above feature? Have you found any library or any piece of code?

Comment: @AraBadalyan, Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use opengl es for filter. By using different shader code you can implement different filter.
Here is useful link https://www.virag.si/2014/03/rendering-video-with-opengl-on-android/

Comment: Thanks for answer. But the problem is that i want add filter dynamically. For example add filter when user click the button.

Comment: you can change filter by changing shader program dynamically i have implemented dynamically.